# Need Help aligning an image in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

Please can you assist me with my query. I am trying to get a shadow png to line up with the edge of a box. I have 3 images posing as shadows and the last shadow, namely "top_right" simply will not fall into place no matter what I try with margins. Below is the code and I would appreciate any assistance.

Sash

```
    <style type="text/css">
body    {
            background-color:#e1f2ff;
            font-family:TW Cen MT;
            }

    h1  { color:#000;
    }

#footer {
    background-color:#313131;
        color:#fff;
        font-style:italic;
                    }
input#box {
            background:#efd2a7;
            font-size:10pt;
            }

        #content {

            background-width:600px;
                }


                    a:hover#butt    {
                        background:url("images/butt_over.png");
                            }

                #top_left {
                    margin-left:-17px;
                    {

                    #top_right {
                        margin-right:300px;
                        }


                    #bott {
                        margin-top:10px;
                        }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container" style="width:900px; height:900px;" align="center">

        <div id="header" align="center">
        <h2>We’re currently constructing our website.
    Please leave your name and e-mail address below and we will
    let you know when the site launches.
    You will also receive fantastic offers & a
    discount voucher for your time!</h2></div>

    <div id="content" style="background-color:#fff;height:450px;width:550px;">

    <img src="images/shad_top_left.png" id="top_left" style="float:left; vertical-align:top" >
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="300" height="100">
    <img src="images/shad_top_right.png" id="top_right" style="float:right;" ><br/>
    <h2>Send us your e-mail address</h2>
    <br/><br/>
```

Comment: Provide a fiddle link with your HTML, CSS, Script files and linked images.

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WfMFZ/)

Comment: I have not used Fiddle before... assuming this is the link http://jsfiddle.net/YL6wn/

Comment: ok that code is updated now to make more sense

Comment: Hi Guys, Please help me as I cannot find an answer

Answer (score 0):

2 errors in your code first you need to close every open bracket at the end of top left youve opened another bracket rather than closed the eisting one .... also use position:absolute

```
            #top_left {
                margin-left:-17px;
                    } // you had put { here instead

                #top_right {
                    position: absolute;
                    margin-left :300px;
                    }
```